# Jquery tabs not working in Wordpress admin panel

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

Accidently jquery tabs stopped working in my wordpress admin panel

Here is the error message

```js
jquery.form.js?ver=4.2.13:902 [jquery.form] terminating; zero elements found by selector
jquery.form.js?ver=4.2.13:902 [jquery.form] terminating; zero elements found by selector
jquery.form.js?ver=4.2.13:902 [jquery.form] terminating; zero elements found by selector
jquery.form.js?ver=4.2.13:902 [jquery.form] terminating; zero elements found by selector
tab.js?ver=4.2.13:142 Uncaught TypeError: jQuery(...).tabs is not a function
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (tab.js?ver=4.2.13:142)
    at j (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,plupload&ver=4.2.13:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,plupload&ver=4.2.13:2)
    at Function.ready (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,plupload&ver=4.2.13:2)
    at HTMLDocument.J (load-scripts.php?c=0&load[]=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,utils,plupload&ver=4.2.13:2)
```

previously I added Qtranslate plugin and its plugins for ACF and Yoast SEO plugins. I turned them off, but problem still appears.

Working admin panel had such scripts includings:

```js
<script type='text/javascript' src='<SITENAME>/wp-admin/load-scripts.php?c=0&amp;load%5B%5D=jquery-core,jquery-migrate,jquery-ui-core,jquery-ui-widget,jquery-ui-mouse,utils,plupload,jquery-ui-resizable,jquery-ui-draggabl&amp;load%5B%5D=e,jquery-ui-button,jquery-ui-position,jquery-ui-dialog,farbtastic,jquery-form&amp;ver=4.2.13'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<SITENAME>/wp-content/themes/wp_oswad_market/js/wd_menu_back.js?ver=4.2.13'></script>
<!--[if lt IE 8]>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<SITENAME>/wp-includes/js/json2.min.js?ver=2011-02-23'></script>
<![endif]-->
<script type='text/javascript' src='<SITENAME>/wp-content/plugins/wp-all-export-pro/static/js/pmxe.js?ver=1.1.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<SITENAME>/wp-content/plugins/admin-menu-editor/js/admin-helpers.js?ver=20140312'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<SITENAME>/wp-content/themes/wp_oswad_market/framework/js/jquery.form.js?ver=4.2.13'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<SITENAME>/wp-content/themes/wp_oswad_market/framework/admin/js/tab.js?ver=4.2.13'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<SITENAME>/wp-content/themes/wp_oswad_market/framework/admin/js/shortcode.js?ver=4.2.13'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<SITENAME>/wp-content/themes/wp_oswad_market/framework/admin/js/page_config.js?ver=4.2.13'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<SITENAME>/wp-content/themes/wp_oswad_market/js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?ver=4.2.13'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<SITENAME>/wp-content/themes/wp_oswad_market/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.js?ver=4.2.13'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<SITENAME>/wp-content/themes/wp_oswad_market/framework/admin/js/logo-upload.js?ver=4.2.13'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<SITENAME>/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js?ver=2.3.8'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.4.7/webfont.js?ver=4.2.13'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<SITENAME>/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/lib/vcIconPicker/jquery.fonticonpicker.min.js?ver=4.2.13'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<SITENAME>/wp-content/plugins/advanced-spoiler/js/spoiler-admin.js?ver=2.02'></script>
```

Now it looks like :

```js
<script type='text/javascript' src='<SITENAME>/wp-content/plugins/wp-all-export-pro/static/js/pmxe.js?ver=1.1.0'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<SITENAME>/wp-content/plugins/admin-menu-editor/js/admin-helpers.js?ver=20140312'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<SITENAME>/wp-content/themes/wp_oswad_market/framework/js/jquery.form.js?ver=4.2.13'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<SITENAME>/wp-content/themes/wp_oswad_market/framework/admin/js/tab.js?ver=4.2.13'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<SITENAME>/wp-content/themes/wp_oswad_market/framework/admin/js/shortcode.js?ver=4.2.13'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<SITENAME>/wp-content/themes/wp_oswad_market/framework/admin/js/page_config.js?ver=4.2.13'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<SITENAME>/wp-content/themes/wp_oswad_market/js/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?ver=4.2.13'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<SITENAME>/wp-content/themes/wp_oswad_market/js/bootstrap-colorpicker.js?ver=4.2.13'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<SITENAME>/wp-content/themes/wp_oswad_market/framework/admin/js/logo-upload.js?ver=4.2.13'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<SITENAME>/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/chosen/chosen.jquery.min.js?ver=2.3.8'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<SITENAME>/wp-content/plugins/advanced-custom-fields-pro/assets/js/acf-input.min.js?ver=5.5.10'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<SITENAME>/wp-content/plugins/acf-qtranslate/assets/common.js?ver=4.2.13'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<SITENAME>/wp-content/plugins/advanced-custom-fields-pro/pro/assets/js/acf-pro-input.min.js?ver=5.5.10'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<SITENAME>/wp-content/plugins/acf-qtranslate/assets/acf_5/main.js?ver=4.2.13'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<SITENAME>/wp-content/plugins/acf-qtranslate/assets/acf_5/qtranslatex.js?ver=4.2.13'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<SITENAME>/wp-content/plugins/woocommerce/assets/js/select2/select2.min.js?ver=3.5.2'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<SITENAME>/wp-content/plugins/advanced-custom-fields-pro/assets/inc/timepicker/jquery-ui-timepicker-addon.min.js?ver=1.6.1'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/webfont/1.4.7/webfont.js?ver=4.2.13'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<SITENAME>/wp-content/plugins/js_composer/assets/lib/vcIconPicker/jquery.fonticonpicker.min.js?ver=4.2.13'></script>
<script type='text/javascript' src='<SITENAME>/wp-content/plugins/advanced-spoiler/js/spoiler-admin.js?ver=2.02'></script>
```

What could be the cause of the error?

Comment: Have you tried removing them completely? Also I still see ACF plugin scripts in your "now it looks like" which could be causing the issue?

Comment: Yes, I deactivated those (and some other) plugins, that didn`t help and I restored plugins. In some pages ACF and other plugins are not using at all, even without deactivation, so scripts not included there, but error appears anyway.